# Domain name won't resolve to VPS

Tags: nginx, centos, cloudflare, digital-ocean, virtualmin

I have DO VPS running on Cent OS 7. I installed nginx and Virtual min.
I am not able to resolve my domai to the VPS. I have created a A record pointing to my Floating IP(static IP) in cloudflare and a CNAME www with a value @. I used the same settings before, it was working. I destroyed my droplet and rebuilded it again but I have assigned the same static IP to the VPS. I have allowed ports 80,443 and 10000.

I have configured my nginx.conf to listen on port 443 too. But still it my domain name does not resolve to my VPS.
Here is my nginx.conf

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
    }

    # Settings for a TLS enabled server.
    #
    #    server {
    #        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    #        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    #        server_name  _;
    #        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #
    #        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
    #        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
    #        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    #        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    #        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #
    #        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    #        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    #
    #        location / {
    #        }
    #
    #        error_page 404 /404.html;
    #            location = /40x.html {
    #        }
    #
    #        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #            location = /50x.html {
    #        }
    #    }

     server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
     server {
     server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
     listen 174.138.xxx.x;
     root /home/mydomain/public_html;
     index index.html index.htm index.php;
     access_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_access_log;
     error_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_error_log;
     fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
     fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/mydomain/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/mydomain/public_html;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-nginx/152112218423330.sock/socket;
    }
    listen 174.138.xxx.x:443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    ssl_certificate /home/mydomain/ssl.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/mydomain/ssl.key;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
    gzip on;
    ssl on;
    }
    }
```

I tried checking if the ports are listening using  netstat -an | grep 443 | grep -i listen and they seem to be listening. Here is my output

```
 tcp        0      0 174.138.xxx.x:443       0.0.0.0:*                     LISTEN
```

Comment: Give us the domain so we can take a look at its DNS.

Comment: thesatlight.com

Comment: All I see is a new WordPress installation. Edit or delete it, then start writing!

Comment: Figured out the issue myself and sorted it out.Posted the updated code as an answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few duplicate entries as well as misconfigured entries. Here is the updated code :

```
  user nginx;

  worker_processes auto;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  pid /run/nginx.pid;

  include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

  events {
  worker_connections 1024;
  }

  http {

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile            on;
  tcp_nopush          on;
  tcp_nodelay         on;
  keepalive_timeout   65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type        application/octet-stream;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


  server {

  listen       80 default_server;
  listen       [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name  mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

  root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

  include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

  location / {

  }

   error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
  }
  }

  server {

  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;


  root /home/mydomain/public_html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  access_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_access_log;

  error_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_error_log;


  location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-nginx/152112218423330.sock/socket;

  fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
  fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
  fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
  fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
  fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
  fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/mydomain/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
  fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
  fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/mydomain/public_html;
  fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
  fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
  fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
  fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
  fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
  fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
  fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 60;   
  }

   ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /home/mydomain/ssl.cert;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/mydomain/ssl.key;

  gzip on;

 }
 }
```